# Spinning gray wheel in mac internet accounts when adding or modifying google logins

Tags: mac, keychain, login

I was getting the spinning gray wheel hang when adding or modifying google accounts when Google Chrome was set as my default browser
[image]

Comment: MacOS Monterey v. 12.0.1

Comment: Try Google Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Setting Safari as my default browser allowed the login to pop up correctly

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. Simply after opening (and closing) Safari once, the pop-up for adding the account in the "Internet accounts" section worked. I did not have to set Safari as the default browser.

Comment: Gotcha, I noticed this worked for me too

Comment: This opened the popup successfully, but once completing the login in the popup, nothing happened. I had to set Safari as the default browser to be able to complete the whole process.